# which one is countable /uncountable set?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

[image]

my attempt ; product of uncountable set is uncountable  as i take $\{0,1\}$ ,as i multiply $\{\{0,1\}.\{0,1\}.\{0,1\}.\{0,1\}.\{0,1\}.\{0,1\}.\{0,1\}.\{0,1\}.
 \{0,1\},,,, = \{0,1\}^n$ which is a uncountable set,,

so my answer is option$2$ ..

is my answer is correct or not , please tell me the solution.

Comment: {0,1} is a finite set

Comment: Why was this photoshopped?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\prod_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}$ is a finite product of finite sets and therefore it is finite. This implies that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\prod_{j=1}^{n}X_{j})$
is a countable union of finite sets and therefore it is...

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that 
$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n): x_i\in\{0,1\}\}\implies \left|\prod_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}\right|=2^n.$$
Moreover for $1\leq n<m$,
$$\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}\right)\cap \left(\prod_{j=1}^{m}X_{j}\right)=\emptyset.$$
Therefore, for any positive integer $m$,
$$\left|\bigcup_{n=1}^m\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}\right)\right|=2+2^2+\dots+ 2^m=2^{m+1}-2$$
What may we conclude?

Comment: ya,,im reading ur solution@ robert,,,im not getting as i know that  product 2^N is uncountable,,, but other  user  saying that answer is countable

Comment: $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable. Here $N$ is just an integer number. The set is countable.

Comment: i mean it is infinite time union,,,my question is that how it can be countable @ Robert

Comment: It is the COUNTABLE union of finite sets. Therefore it is countable.

Comment: @ Robert  can u  pliz more eloborate  how 2^m+1   - 2  is countable

Comment: $2^{m+1} - 2$ means that it is finite. Then $m$ goes to infinity.

Comment: thanks a lots ,,,,,, @Robert Z

Comment: i will vote up u now @ Robert

Comment: @kalomlego: +1 to Robert's answer. A countable union of finite sets is countable.

Comment: thanks,,,,,@parsiad